# Captcha AngularJS validation with button click

Tags: angularjs

In my application, captcha was must be validated with button only. I tried that but when I entered the wrong captcha, form submitted into the database later alert message show captcha was not valid but form was already submitted .

I want to validate that with button click if I entered the wrong captcha, the form should not submit. Please see my fiddle and help me to solve this problem thanks in advance.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  alert("hiiiiii");
  var string1 = removeSpaces($scope.mainCaptcha);
  var string2 = removeSpaces($scope.c);

  if (string1 == string2) {
    alert(true);
  } else {
    alert(false);
  }

  var _EeqObj = new Object();
  _EeqObj.Name = $("#Name").val();
  _EeqObj.Verification_Code = $("#txtInput").val();
  _EeqObj.Meth = "WX";

  var httpreq = $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "api/Home",
    data: _EeqObj
  }).success(function(response) {
    if (response == "success") {
      alert("Thank You");
    } else {
      alert("not inserted");
    }
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6jqmv68d/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`submit()` is submitting the form irrespective of whether captcha is correct or not, so you  need to exit/return out of `submit()` module  when wrong captcha is entered and show a alert message.

**JS CODE:**

```
if (string1 == string2) {
    alert(true);
}
else {
    alert("Wrong captcha, please re enter and submit again");
    return;
}
```

*note:I personally don't like using any 3rd party library with `angularjs`, as it is a over kill, in your case instead of fetching the DOM data using `jquery` use `ng-model` to define a model and refer the same in your controller.*

**Use ng-model instead of jquery DOM traversing**

```
 _EeqObj.Name = $scope.Name;
 _EeqObj.Verification_Code = $scope.c;
```

[Working demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9g0g122h/1/)

Comment: still form was submitted.it doen't validate

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return false` after displaying wrong captcha message since the `ng-submit` doesn't validate any custom invalid data or invalid fields.

```
if (string1 == string2) {
    alert(true);
} else {
    alert(false);
    return false;
}
```